# How to install Rust without getting a timeout error during a file download?

Tags: python, linux, macos, curl, timeout

In a Terminal window on my Mac Pro (OS X 10.9.5), I want to get rust via rustup using the linux command: '$ curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh'

But, this timeout error is printed:

Current installation options:

default host triple: x86_64-apple-darwin
     default toolchain: stable
  modify PATH variable: yes

1) Proceed with installation (default)
2) Customize installation
3) Cancel installation

info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-apple-darwin'
error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to '/Users/laurence/.multirust/tmp/q3f6bbl3suzhpl6m_file
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [28] Timeout was reached (Connection timed out after 30056 milliseconds)
rustup: command failed: /var/folders/rn/slxkq6md5jvcwp99zm0_tq_40000gs/T/rustup.H6IPudqd/rustup-init

Do you have a solution?

Thanks a lot,
Laurence_D

Answer (score 1):

use Homebrew for easily installing stuffs on mac

do to install Homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install rust with the command

`brew install rust`

Comment: Now all is OK ! Thanks Arduino Sentinel.

Comment: Would you mind up voting this as helpful since it help you. Cheers :)